# Boost Spirit X3: How to recover both matched and unmatched results of a rule

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-spirit-x3

Consider the following sample text line:

"Hello **:** World 2020  :tag1:tag2:tag3"

I want to design a spirit X3 parser that can extract:

1. Content := "Hello **:** world 2020  "
2. Tags    := { tag1,tag2,tag3 }

**The problem**: Content is defined as leftover char sequence(excluding eol) after matching the tags and  I am not sure how to write a rule that can synthesize two attributes: one representing the extracted tags and another representing leftover characters(the content)

So far I've written the rule for extracting the tags:

```cpp
       ...
    namespace ast { 
      struct sample {
         std::u32string content;
         std::vector<std::u32string> tags;  
      };
      //BOOST FUSION STUFF .....
    }

   namespace grammar {

       using x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
       using x3::unicode::lit;
       using x3::unicode::char_;
       using x3::unicode::alnum;

       auto const tag
       = x3::rule<class tag_class, std::u32string> {"tag"}
            %=
            lit(U":")
            >>
            +(alnum | lit(U"_") | lit(U"@") | lit(U"#") | lit(U"%") )
            ;

       auto const tags
       = x3::rule<class tags_class, std::vector<std::u32string>{"tags"}
            %= +tag >> lit(U":");
    }
```

But stuck over here:

```cpp
  auto const sample_rule = 
     = x3::rule<class sample_rule_class, ast::sample> {"sample"}
     = ?? // something like (+char_ - (eol|tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a much elegant solution out there. In the meantime, a messy solution:

1. Parse each sample line as a single string unit.
2. Use semantic action to filer out the **tags** from each matched string unit.
3. Discard the filtered tags from the string unit to be left with only **content**.

sample_ast.h

```c++
#prgama once
#include <string>

namespace ast {

struct sample {
std::u32string              content;
std::vector<std::u32string> tags;
};

}
```

sample.h

```c++
#pgrama once
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/char_encoding/unicode.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include "sample_ast.hpp"

//tags property is intentionally ignored.
//It will be synthesized
//manually using semantic actions
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( ast::sample,content )

namespace grammar { 
namespace detail  {

using x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
using     x3::unicode::char_;
using     x3::eol;
using     x3::eoi;
using     x3::lexeme;

auto const sample_line 
 = x3::rule<class sample_line_class, std::u32string>{"sample_line"}
 = lexeme[ +(char_ - (eol|eoi)) ];

auto filter_tags = /*.... definition moved to next page for clarity */

auto const sample
=  x3::rule<class sample, ast::sample >{"sample"}
=% filter_tags[ sample_line ];
}}

namespace grammar {
  using grammar::detail::sample;
}
```

**filter_tags definition**
iterate the matched data right to left collecting
colon separated tags until an invalid tag char is
encountered or all chars have been exhausted.
`pos_saved` is used to track the beginning
of the tag list, which is used to discard the tags
from the content after collecting them into the ast.

```c++
    auto filter_tags = []( auto& context )
    {
                         
       auto &attr = _attr(context);  // content string
       auto &val  = _val(context);   // ast::sample
    
       std::stack<char32_t> mem;
       auto        pos       = attr.rbegin();
       auto& const pos_end   = attr.rend();
       auto        pos_saved = atrr.end();
       do{

         //tag start or end          
         if( *pos == U':' ){
     
            if( mem.empty() ) {  //tag start

                mem.push(U':'); 
            }
            else { //tag end

                 //tag closed state:
                 //all chars for the current tag
                 //are ready for transfer into
                 //the ast.
                  
                 std::u32string tag;
                 while( mem.top() != ':' ){
                      
                      //since we're reverse iterating the data
                      //the tags wont be backwards 
                      tag.push_back( mem.top());
                      mem.pop();
                 } 

                 val.tags.push_back(tag);
                 //update the start offset of
                 //that tags
                 pos_saved = pos.base();   
            } 

         } else { // tag char or not

                using u = spirit::char_encoding::unicode; 
                if( !mem.empty() ) {   
                   if(u::isalnum(*pos)) mem.push( *pos ); //tag char found 
                   else                 break;            //invalid tag char found  
                }
                else {
                   //space after tag list but before content end 
                   if(u::isspace(*pos) pos_saved = pos.base(); 
                }
        }              
       }while(++pos != pos_end);

       if( pos_saved != attr.end()) attr.erase(pos_saved, attr.end() );
       if( attr.empty() )           _pass(context) = false;     
    };
```